# Submit button not working anymore in new review queue layout

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, triage

I was just reviewing some posts and noticed that the review queue page layout has changed (in this case *Triage*). While this layout is nice and works much better on mobile devices, there seems to be a bug in this queue:

Once I select an option from the "actions" menu, the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button is activated. But when I click it, nothing happens (both in Firefox on a Linux desktop PC as well as on Chrome on Android).

In the past, a submenu opened in which I was asked to specify the detailed reason (e.g. "Needs details or clarity" or "Needs more focus"), but now, I am stuck at this point.

[image]

**Edit:** It seems that displaying the submenu with the subsequent choices in the *Triage* review queue is indeed the problem: I can click the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button when I select one of the options "Looks OK" or "Needs community edit" (which do not have suboptions). If I select "Flag", the dialog with suboptions is also correctly displayed after clicking <kbd>Submit</kbd>, but not after selecting "Needs author edit". So either the submenu is not displayed or it is located somewhere off-screen, I guess.

The problem is also not present in other review queues where the items in the "Actions" menu do not prompt for subchoices (as e.g. in the *First Posts* queue).

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me (Firefox on macOS).

Comment: Interesting, still no luck here. Once you select for instance "Needs author edit", does a submenu pop up?

Comment: Yeah, it pops up the usual close dialog and then choosing an option from there completes the review. Though now that I say that, I'm wondering if it might have something to do with whether you have the close vote privilege. No easy way for me to test that unfortunately.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Could be! (Though I can't test it, also.) With the "Flag" radio selected, "Submit" first displays a flag-selection popup before moving on to close reasons; however, "Needs author edit" goes straight to the "Close..." popup (in my case), so maybe you have a point.

Comment: [The announcement post on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/348196).

Comment: I added a reference to this question below the announcement post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361336/906916

Comment: This is happening to me in Edge (Chromium). The submit button clicks - it's not disabled, but I get no additional dialog. I have to Skip the question or choose another outcome.

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole The "Needs author edit" is superfluous. The option isn't  needed. It just creates confusion. Pick "Flag" and "needs improvement" which will get you to do the exact same place with the exact same options as if you had picked "Needs author edit".

Comment: @Scratte, I don't disagree with that semantically, they are the same in meaning, but I only get so many Flags in a day (across all queues?) and it's easy to run out, and only be left the option to downvote and/or comment, then Skip.

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole You're still going to use a flag when choosing "Needs author edit". It raises a flag (a close flag) on the post.

Comment: Well then I guess I don't really care how it's implemented, but "dead" user interface is really irritating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the report - here's what happened.

Basically, in order for Recommend Close (or Needs Author Edit) to function properly, the JavaScript relies on a (hidden) close link in the post menu to be present on the page. However, we only included the close link for users who had close permissions. Therefore, when you tried to perform that action, it just failed silently because it couldn't find the button to click. I fixed this by including the hidden close link for both users who can close questions as well as users who can recommend question closure.

The fix will be in the next build, which probably won't go out until tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the quick fix! Cheers!

Comment: Just confirmed that it is now rolled out and indeed fixed. It works now. Thanks!